# I cant force a image to center inside a div

Tags: css

i have a simple image slider, the problem is that the transition effect takes off on the left of the container, duplicating the image, here is the example:
http://ivangodfather.no-ip.org:84/studio/es/proyectos/proyectos/edificio-fs

The solution could be to center the img in the div with class "box_clone", but i tried with no success.

Comment: Why is the image being loaded twice?

Comment: I think u want this http://tinkerbin.com/4EA0WdrX

Comment: please post some code to clarify wat u r asking for.Some jsfiddle would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since the image is in the DIV and not a CSS backbround, you can just use

```
width: XXXpx; margin: 0 auto;
```

on the div and remove box_clone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add css rule `text-align:center;` to div, containing an image.
Sorry if i'm wrong, i can't see provided example now.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to the div

```
style="background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-position: center;"
```

Comment: what? this makes no sense, have you seen the problem? theres no div with background image or so.

Comment: den where r u showing up ur images. can u post some code den to clarify what u r asking for